# How to parse JSON value in iPad?

Tags: json, ipad, parsing, nsdictionary

Using SBJSON parser to parse JSON value from server, i have received response like

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

 NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

json_string value here:

```
{ "status": true, "result": { "nid": "1116", "title": "PeopleSoft Enterprise HCM 91 Release Notes.pdf", "status": "1", "uid": "1", "body": "\x3cp\x3e\x3ca href=\"http://www.carinsuranceiseasy.com/\"\x3echeapest auto insurance\x3c/a\x3e wttig \x3ca href=\"http://www.lifeinsuranceshopping.net/\"\x3elife insurance quotes\x3c/a\x3e 304 \x3ca href=\"http://www.bestautoinsurancepolicies.net/\"\x3eaffordable auto insurance\x3c/a\x3e 39292\x3c/p\x3e", "splitpdfs": [  ], "mail": "gumpagain@gmail.com", "name": "admin", "pdf": "http://www.publishgenie.com/sites/default/files/pdf_convert/2012/12/19/1355908128-986.pdf", "page_number": "249", "filesize": 8936895, "referrallink": "http://www.publishgenie.com/index.php?q=ebook-referral/530/1116/19f80281e0ad314423afb51a5322e2ac" } }
```

then i tried to set the value in NSDictionary but the dictionar value always null, how to parse this? please help me.

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
SBJSON * parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
  NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)[parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using SBJSON? You can use the build in parser:

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

**Edit:**
Also you Json String is invalid. [You can use a site like this to check you json](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)